# What is the best way to test a string?

Tags: powershell, operators

I'm testing some string using this notation

```
if ($someString -eq "someValue") { ... }
```

But I've read some examples online where values are tested with `-like` operator

```
if ($someString -like "someValue") { ... }
```

The result appears to be the same in all situation (note that  I'm talking about strings). Is there any difference and/or best practice to follow or there is no differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-eq` is for strict equality.

with `-like` you can use wildcards but in your case it acts like `-eq`

EDIT:
Best practice is to use `-eq` if you dont really need `-like`

Answer (score -1):

`-eq` checks if `$someString` is exactly the same as `$someValue`

and when

`-like` when used with wildcards it checks if the `$someString` contains some substring of `$someValue`, otherwise it works same as `-eq`

`-contains` - check weather there is a substring in `$someString`

Practically `-eq` is most commolny the one to use, using `-like` with wildcards can give you some unexpected false positives, however if you do not need so strict checking can reduce the number of conditions needed.

Comment: No, `-like` *without wildcards* will act the same as `-eq`. Only `-match` can give false positives, as it uses regex where `'Foo' -match 'o'`. But `'Foo' -notlike 'o'`.

Comment: Probably you confused `-like` and `-contains`